# SED - Deleting occurences of first line through the rest of the file

Tags: csv, sed, text-files

I'm stuck in something that looks like it should be simple to SED.

I have some (kind of) CSV files that I get from another application, so I cannot control its output. Some preprocessing is already done with SED, but I am stuck on the last one. So I wish to do it with SED, if possible, to avoid using a third application.

The problem is that the heading line of the file (first line) is repeated along the file, but unfortunately with the following characteristics:

1. The heading of each CSV file is unknown previously. Each file have its own heading, that might be different from each other;
2. Not always repetition occurs on every N lines (being N a fixed known number)
3. Other data (non heading) lines might be repeated, and should be maintained

So, suppose I have the following 2 files:

Cash.csv

```
Name; Amount
John; 3.55
Erick; 4.76
John; 8.99
Name; Amount
Erick; 4.76
Mark; 1.00
Name; Amount
John; 3.55
```

Check.csv

```
Name; Account; Amount
Erick; 345344; 123.00
Mark; 88849; 323.50
Name; Account; Amount
John; 474473; 99.00
Mark; 88849; 323.50
Mark; 88849; 323.50
John; 474473; 99.00
```

What I wish is a single SED script that applied to each file turn them into:

Cash.processed.csv

```
Name; Amount
John; 3.55
Erick; 4.76
John; 8.99
Erick; 4.76
Mark; 1.00
John; 3.55
```

Check.processed.csv

```
Name; Account; Amount
Erick; 345344; 123.00
Mark; 88849; 323.50
John; 474473; 99.00
Mark; 88849; 323.50
Mark; 88849; 323.50
John; 474473; 99.00
```

I was wondering if its possible to use SED "hold buffer" as a pattern on the delete command:

```
1h     #Hold the first line (headings)
/\h/d  #Use hold buffer as a pattern to delete
```

Supposing "\h" would return the hold buffer to the delete command.

Thanks for any replies;

PS: Please don't answer with the following over-specific command:

```
1p;/Name; Amount\|Name; Account; Amout/d
```

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the tip. Not enough reputation yet, but as soon as I get it I'll mark it as helpful. I am a long time readonly Stack Overflow fan. I didn't expect to get helpful answers that fast, so now I am a huge SO fan. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to capture the first line from one `sed` command and then use that in the main operational command:

```
line1=$(sed 1q $datafile)

sed -e "2,$ {/$line1/d;}" \
    -e '...rest of sed script...' $datafile
```

Because the `sed 1q` quits after reading the first line, it is quick regardless of how big the data file is. If there's a chance that the first line might contain a slash (heading `"Name/Number"`, perhaps) or other regex metacharacters, then think of using something like this, which replaces all slashes with `.`:

```
line1=$(sed '1{s%/%.%g;q;}' $datafile)
```

I did some futzing with the Mac OS X (10.8.1) version of `sed`, which is fussier than GNU `sed`.  In the second (main) `sed` command, the match had to be in `{...}`, the dollar had to be separate (or the shell gets antsy about invalid parameter substitution), and the semi-colon was needed.  Some of those restrictions probably aren't needed with GNU `sed`, but the code shown is likely to work anywhere.

Comment: +1 This is how I'd do it, too. If the first line could contain regex metacharacters, they will need to be escaped.

Comment: Works like a charm, and fast too. It took me about 0.5 second for a 1 million lines file (20MB).

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!{G;/^\(.*\)\n\1/d;s/\n.*//}' file
```

Explanation:

- `1h` store the heading line in the hold space (HS) and print.
- `1!{G;/^\(.*\)\n\1/d;s/\n.*//}` for every line but the first, append a newline followed by the contents of the HS (i.e. the heading line). Compare the first part of the line to the heading line and if it's the same delete that line. If it's not delete the appended newline and heading line and print as normal.

EDIT:

This is indeed very slow on large files, a quicker and perhaps easier to understand solution is:

```
sed 's|.*|1!{/^&$/d}|;q' file | sed -f - file
```

This makes a sed script from the first line of the input file.

Comment: Thanks potong. For small files I guess that this 1 line sed is the best alternative. But for bigger files this can get really slow. It took me 10 seconds for a 1 million lines file (20MB) versus 0.5 second for the Jonathan alternative (see accepted answer).

Comment: @RFVoltolini: Your timing of the results is interesting.  Potong's sed expression has to copy each line, extend it, use a modestly complex regex on it (the `\1` in the regex makes it complex, at least for the time it takes to execute it) and then generally remove the extension to the line, so it isn't altogether surprising that it is slower than a simple regex match.  I am a little surprised that it is 20 times slower, though.  It is a clever expression, though, potong.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are interested in awk:

```
awk '{if(NR==1){p=$0;print}if(NR>1 && p!=$0)print}' your_file
```

Comment: Or more briefly: `NR == 1 { p=$0 }; NR == 1 || p != $0`.

Comment: or more briefly `NR==1&&p=$0;p!=$0`

Comment: WOW! Small, fast and powerfull! I guess I'll have to take some time to learn awk and rewrite my hole script.